# IN predicate with a list in JOOQ return just the first value

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a simple select in JOOQ with IN(List) predicate, but the result of this query is just for the first element in the list.

```
        List<Integer> ids = context.select(TABLE1.ID).from(TABLE1).where(
                TABLE1.NAME.eq(name)).fetch().into(Integer.class);

        List<MyObject> myObjectList = context.selectFrom(TABLE2)
                .where(TABLE2.ID.in(ids))
                .fetch().into(MyObject.class);
```

Data samples

First query result-> List Ids={1,2,3,4}

TABLE2 content ->
MyObject (1, A), 
MyObject (2, B), 
MyObject (3, C), 
MyObject(4, D)
........., 
MyObject(21, Z)

Second query result -> MyObject(1, A)

Comment: can you provide some sample data..

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post

Comment: This is not related to the question but I think I would make this with one query with join and not 2.

Comment: Are you sure your transaction actually has that "table2 content" available?

Comment: @ Varvarigos Emmanouil: I know, but the real query was complex and I tryed to split for a better debug

Comment: @Lukas Eder: yes, the transaction was fine.

Comment: I've just solved, was a syntax problem in the first query, JOOQ need a Field object to iterare in the right way.  (EDIT IN THE ORIGINAL POST)
Thank you for the responses :)

Comment: Thanks for showing your solution. Note instead of editing your question, the recommended way to do that here on Stack Overflow is to answer your own question.

Comment: However, note that what you found here is a workaround (the result is actually better, because you only have a single roundtrip). But the first solution you've had should still work. Would be curious to see an example that helps reproduce the issue. If you have some time, I'd appreciate an MCVE: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Comment: @Lukas Eder: Ok, done, I'm quite new in Stack Overflow, any suggestion to do better it's appreciate :)

I found the first solution in the JOOQ documentation, but after many hours lost 
to understand the problem, I noticed that the result was only for the first element in the list.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

The problem was the first query syntax.

```
Field<Integer> ids = context.select(TABLE1.ID).from(TABLE1).where(
                TABLE1.NAME.eq(name)).asField();

List<MyObject> myObjectList = context.selectFrom(TABLE2)
                .where(TABLE2.ID.in(ids))
                .fetch().into(MyObject.class);
```